# Cuda 2D memory allocation and copy problem

Tags: c, memory-management, cuda

```
   int **F;
   int **dev_pF;
   size_t *pitchF;
   void init_cuda_mem(int mF,int mT,int nF,int nT){

    cudaMallocPitch((void **)dev_pF,pitchF,(nF + 2*nT -2)*sizeof(int),mF + 2*mT -2);
    cudaMemcpy2D((void *)dev_pF,*pitchF,(void *)pF,*pitchF,(nF + 2*nT -2)*sizeof(int),mF + 2*mT -2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   }
```

Well hello everyone

in the above snippet i am trying to allocate a 2D array using cudaMallocPitch

and then copying that array using cudaMemcpy2D from the host to the device

unfortunately it crashes and i think the error is (i think) at the cudaMemcpy2D

can someone help me locate it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are mistaken with regards to pointers and pointers to pointers.

You should probably do something on the lines of:

```
int *dev_pF;
size_t pitchF;

void init_cuda_mem(int mF,int mT,int nF,int nT) {
    cudaMallocPitch((void **)&dev_pF, &pitchF,(nF + 2*nT -2)*sizeof(int),mF + 2*mT -2);
    cudaMemcpy2D((void *)dev_pF,pitchF,(void *)pF, pitchF,(nF + 2*nT -2)*sizeof(int),mF + 2*mT -2,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

Note the difference that you are now taking the address of the variables in the cudaMallocPitch call and then just using them directly in the second call.

In your original code, you were first asking cudaMalloc to store a pointer in whatever memory dec_pF happened to point to and store the size in whatever memory pitchF was pointing to. Both of these where unitialized, so disaster could occur there. In the second call you were converting dev_pF from a pointer to pointer to a regular pointer, so you are telling the memcpy to copy memory starting where the pointer was stored rather than where the allocated memory was stored. And since both the pointer to pointer and the size where unitialized at first, pretty much anything could happen.

Also, you are making use of a pF pointer that I cannot see in the original code, make sure it is initialized properly.